# Trying to understand why a type is not Send

Tags: rust

I have the following struct:

```
pub struct TrafficGenerator {
    settings: Settings,
    token: String,
    users: Arc<Mutex<Vec<User>>>,
}
```

I'm unable to pass it to a `tokio::spawn()` as the compiler complains it's not `Send`. The culprit here seems to be `Arc<Mutex<Vec<User>>>` as the compiler complains `the trait 'Send' is not implemented for 'std::sync::MutexGuard<'_, Vec<User>>'`. Here, we have

```
pub struct User {
    account: Account,
    token: String,
}

pub struct Account {
    id: String,
}
```

Could someone explain what the problem is? I read Rustonomicon's comments about `Send`, but got no wiser for this particular case. I don't see anything in the definition of `User` that would cause it to be non-send. Are there any trait implementations that would cause the compiler to make some of the nested types not `Send`?

EDIT: The code where the problem happens is the following:

```
let task_permits = Arc::new(Semaphore::new(0));
let request_permits = Arc::new(Semaphore::new(0));
let users = Arc::new(Mutex::new(Vec::from(users)));

for _ in 0..settings.tasks {
    let users = users.clone();
    let generator = TrafficGenerator::new(settings, users);
    let task_permits = task_permits.clone();
    let request_permits = request_permits.clone();
    let token = cancel_token.clone();
    tokio::spawn(async move {
        select! {
            _ = generator.start(task_permits, request_permits) => {}
            _ = token.cancelled() => {}
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You need to include the Future you're passing to `tokio::spawn` in your question.

Comment: @drewtato: Added the calling code.

Comment: Are you holding the `MutexGuard` across an `.await` point in `TrafficGenerator::start()`? That would cause the future to become `!Send`.

Comment: Ah. That is the problem. In a loop it chooses a single &User from the vector and passes it to the function that does a gRPC request, so it's still holding on to the lock as it's borrowing an element from the vector. Need to copy the User.